# Integral of an irrational function

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I would like to ask a question on finding the integral of an irrational function.

1. I have learnt so far that for $y=\sin^{-1}(f(x)), \frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1-(f(x)^2)}}$and thus the anti derivative is given as : integrate $\frac{f'(x)}{\sqrt{1-(f(x)^2)}}$ wrtx, will get me back y.
2. So, is it possible for me to get back $y = \cos^{-1}(f(x))$ by integrating its derivative, that is : $\frac{dy}{dx}= \frac{-f'(x)}{\sqrt{1-(f(x)^2)}}$?

I have tried to search on the internet for pt2. but I cannot seem to find the relationship. Is it valid or is it not? Thank you so much :)

Comment: Please verify the edit and learn MathJax. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: I would say, this does not apply without the integration constants.

Comment: Yes, that is valid.  However, if you already know the anti-derivative of $sin^{-1}(x)$, then $\int\frac{-f'(x)}{\sqrt{1- (f(x))^2}} dx=$$ -\int\frac{-f'(x)}{\sqrt{1- (f(x))^2}}dx= -sin^{-1}(x)+ C$.   Of course, $cos^{-1}(x)+ C= sin^{-1}(x)+ C'$ for some constants C and C'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes definitely you'll get back

Integral reverses the effect done by differentiation, thus anti derivative.
Given$$y=cos^{−1}(f(x))$$
Differentiating 
$$\implies y' = \frac{-f'(x)}{\sqrt{1-(f(x)^2)}} $$
Integrating
$$\int\frac{-f'(x)}{\sqrt{1-(f(x)^2)}}\text{d}x$$
$$\implies \int y' \text{d}x$$
$$cos^{−1}(f(x)) +C$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is valid because $\cos \alpha=\sin (\frac{\pi}{2}-\alpha)$, so:
$$
\cos^{-1} x=\frac{\pi}{2}-\sin^{-1} x
$$

So the two integrals differs only by the sign and a constant .